# VS Code JS color theme won't paint some of the code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, themes

Why VS code won't paint some of my code, while I know that this keyword has a specific color?

[image]

For example, the console.log should be in yellow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a conflicting theme extension. Can you try disabling any extension that could be doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is what caused it:

[image]

Disabling this option solved it fr me!